# Route all traffic through a socks proxy w/ vpn?

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I know it's possible with tun2socks of badvpn. However, I cannot get past an error "connection reset by peer". This is a proxy I'm paying for and my IP address is the only verified one on the account. So I know that my connections should be going through and that the proxy is stable. I have tested it with other software and it works. It just isn't working with tun2socks. Does anyone know if I could possibly do this with openvpn instead? If not, can someone help me figure out why I'm getting, "connection reset by peer" with tun2socks?